# plist data fetching based on its value

Tags: iphone, ios5, plist

I have one plist as below, In this plist i want to fetch all the records baded on one value. Here I want to fetch all menuCategory names based on Value of MenuType. If user slect MenuTyp as veg i want to fetch all menuCatogory whodse Menutype is veg.  Here is plis structure please help??

```
<dict>
            <key>MenuType</key>
            <string>NonVeg</string>
            <key>MenuCategory</key>
            <string>MainCourse</string>
            <key>MenuName</key>
            <string>KababHandi</string>
            <key>MenuPrice</key>
            <string>200</string>
            <key>MenuContents</key>
            <string>Kabab, Meat Masala, Salt</string>
        </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is going to help you.

```
NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *dataDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];

NSArray *catArray = [dataDict allKeys];
```

Comment: that i know i want to fetch menuCategory based on ite type

Comment: NSArray *catArray = [dataDict allKeys]; is your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *plistFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"YourPlistFileName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *yourDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];

    NSlog(@"%@",[yourDict objctForKey:@"MenuType"]);
    NSlog(@"%@",[yourDict objctForKey:@"MenuCategory"]);
    NSlog(@"%@",[yourDict objctForKey:@"MenuName"]);
    NSlog(@"%@",[yourDict objctForKey:@"MenuPrice"]);
    NSlog(@"%@",[yourDict objctForKey:@"MenuContents"]);
```

Comment: you are assigning array to Dictionary, It will just crash

Comment: that is the same answer of mine

Comment: not that..compare it... if u have another way to get data from plist then please put it as answer. :)